# Javascript - Filter an array of objects (instruments) and return instruments that are strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-filter

Here are the instructions I was given:

- Create an object called orchestra

The object should have the following properties:

- name(string)   // choose any value you like
- instruments // (array of objects with properties (name and section))
- director(string)   // choose any value you like
  The instruments property should be an array of 5 objects with properties called "name" and "section".  Examples:  a violin would be in the string section, a trumpet would be in the brass section .  You need to set the array with 5 of these objects.
- Create a function that would filter through the  orchestra's instruments and console log the array of instruments that belong to the string section only.

```
var orchestra = {};
        orchestra.name = "Shawn";
        orchestra.instruments = [
            {
                "name": "Guitar",
                "section": "String"
            },
            {
                "name": "Violin",
                "section": "String"
            },
            {
                "name": "Bass",
                "section": "String"
            },
            {
                "name": "Flute",
                "section": "Woodwind"
            },
            {
                "name": "Drums",
                "section": "Percussion"
            }
        ];
        orchestra.director = "Wolfgang Mozart";
        
        /********************************************************************/

        var stringInstruments = orchestra.instruments.filter(filterStringInstruments);

        /********************************************************************/

        console.log(stringInstruments);

        /********************************************************************/

        function filterStringInstruments(orchestraInstruments) {
            let result = false;
            if (orchestraInstruments.instruments.section === "String") {
                result = true;
            }
            return result;
        }

        /********************************************************************/
```

I get the following error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'section' of undefined

I don't get why orchestra.instruments.section is undefined. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Should be `orchestraInstruments.section === "String"`